# Change Date Format in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

I have a table where users used to enter random date formats like
**dd/MM/Year** or **MM/dd/Year**.
But I want to update all those dates to this format **Year/MM/dd**
I have made a cursor and changed data by CHAR INDEX and sub string..
but is there any easy way to change the date format to the one i want ?
and also how can I make my default database date format = **Year/mm/dd**
only database not server?

Comment: The only way to make this work reliably is to change your table to use the `DATE` data type, and force them to stop entering the data as text values.

Comment: i'm looking for how to update the records in the table to that dateformat

Comment: There is no logical way for a SQL Server query to determine whether a user who entered '01/12/2015' meant to say January 12th or December 1st.  Unless you have some way of telling whether the month or day comes first, there is no way to differentiate between the random date formats you indicated.

Comment: The `DATE` datatype is what you need to store dates. Any other datatype will get you in trouble.

Comment: thank you for your help guys .. now i made all the data as 'MM/DD/YYYY'
the problem now is when i try to alter the column type to date 
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
there is an error for converting from varchar to date
although the count of this query = 0 ; 
select COUNT(*) from staffYMD where ISDATE(fo)!=1

Comment: never mind i fixed , there was a year = 015
'02/12/015'

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into different styles.

for example:

```
select convert(varchar(15),getdate(),103)
```

will give today's date in dd/mm/yyyy.

Full list of converting styles supported by MSSQL is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)